# How can I fix the Cors Enable issue in an API I created in WSO2 Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

When I call an API that I created in Integration Studio from within a localhost application, I get a CORS error. How can I fix this.?

Although cors enabled  in deployment.toml file.

```
[synapse_properties]
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.enabled' = "true"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Origin' = "*"
'synapse.rest.CORSConfig.Access-Control-Allow-Headers' = "content-type"
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: The problem is CORS ERROR generally

Comment: @AhmetKalem have you got the solution for this issue? I'm also facing the CORS error for localhost.